# ActiveX control in a Excel file gives "Could not load an object..." error on some machines

Tags: excel, vba, com, activex

We are using a set of Excel files on several machines in our company. These files contain a VBA application which utilizes a couple of ActiveX control objects from `mscomct2.ocx` library (namely, `MonthView` and `DateTimePicker`). ActiveX objects are to be displayed in UserForm. Unfortunately the portability of these files seems limited in a very peculiar way.

There appears to be 2 groups of machines:

- **Group A:** I can create a Excel file containing `MonthView` on such machine and work with it on any Group A PC. But when I try to open this file on any machine from Group B, I'm getting a *Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine* error. However, files with the same ActiveX created on Group B machines work normaly on A machines.
- **Group B:** File with an ActiveX in question created on these machines work everywhere (i.e. on any A and B machine). But, as I said earlier, B machines give the error mentioned above when the file with ActiveX saved on A machine is opened.

In one sentence: *files created on A machine work only on other A's, files created on B's work everywhere*!

The strangest thing here is that every machine has `mscomct2.ocx` registered (once again: I can create the form with the `MonthView` **on any machine in question**!). The `.ocx` itself is in place on each machine and the whole set of registry keys is present (CLSIDs for controls classes, IIDs, typelib ID...). In addition, the data in these registry keys seem to be the same on A and B group machines (GUIDs, ProgIDs, versions etc.). There are slight differences in description strings (values like "Microsoft MonthView Control 6.0 (SP6)") on some machines but this does not seem to affect the situation (some machines in B group have such descriptions different but files created on them still work everywhere).

Naturally, thanks to Murphy's law, the machine I use to edit these Excel files belongs to Group A, so files saved here are 'unportable' to B machines...

The OS and Excel versions don't seem to affect the situation. For example, one of B machines is working under Win 7 64 bit (Excel 2007), while most others group A and B machines are Win XP Prof (32 bit) SP3, with Excel 2003 installed. So it seems that OS and Excel versions don't affect compatibility and the problem is somehow connected with ActiveX.

The only ActiveX-related difference between A and B groups I found is the file version of `mscomct2.ocx`: at least several of A machines have version 6.1.x.x, while Group B has 6.0.x.x. I don't see how can such difference cause problems (ActiveX are COM objects after all, and according to registry key values, the exposed typelib, com objects and interfaces seem to be the same in all cases). Nevertheless I tried to replace my 6.1.x.x `ocx` with 6.0.x.x version... and ran into more trouble. What I did is:

1. `regsvr32 /u mscomct2.ocx` - completed successfully
2. Replaced the `mscomct2.ocx` with file of 6.0.x.x version
3. `regsvr32 mscomct2.ocx` - completed successfully

After these steps I tried to make an Excel file with single form containing the `MonthView`. But when I tried to place a control in the form I've got a messagebox with error *Class not registered*. This is really strange cause everything seem to be registered: the control class, its interfaces, typelib (yes, I've checked the registry to be sure). But still the error was there.

After that I did the unregister/replace/register procedure again to go back to my original 6.1.x.x file. That took me back to the original SNAFU situation: I could again install ActiveX to user form and use it, but the Group B machines still gave the error on files saved by my machine.

I assume that the problem of files-with-ActiveX portability and the problem of `ocx` registration are somehow connected, but I don't see how. Perhaps there are some additional requirements for registration of an ActiveX in Excel VBA which I don't know...

The only thing I need is to have the ActiveX object contaned in my Excel file compatible with other machines. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

I think one group (probably "A") has this installed: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10019, another one don't.

Comment: OK. 1. How about this one? http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7474 The rel.notes say it includes the 6.1 version of the controlz that fail.. 2. You could also try moving the 6.0 file to your 6.1 system just like you did, but also repeat your steps 1-3 with another OCX, "comctl32.ocx". P.S. The problem is certainly the DLL hell from the VB 6.0-era.. Check out this thread: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Problem-with-MSCOMCT2-OCX-MSM-td7308299.html

Comment: 1. I am unable to install this update on our PCs: it requires the 'Visual Basic 6 Product' installed. Evidently the VB used in Excel does not count. I even tried this file on a machine with full VS2005 installed (VB included) - same stuff. 2. No effect too :( Thanks for your help, anyway - +1 for your concern.

Comment: P.S. I wish I knew at least which class exactly is "not registered" when im trying to downgrade the ocx. Is there way to learn that?

Comment: OK, then you might try to unpack the MSI (by running "msiexec /a VB60SP6-KB926857-x86-ENU.msi TARGETDIR=C:\Temp\VB6Controls /qb" from the command-line), it'll give you 8 OCX files: comct232.ocx mschrt20.ocx mscomct2.ocx msdatgrd.ocx MSFlxGrd.Ocx mshflxgd.ocx msmask32.ocx mswinsck.ocx, and try to register them all. The included mscomct2.ocx has 6.1.98.12 file version, 6.01.9812 product version.

Comment: P.S. You can use ProcessMonitor utility for that: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645. Just set up the filters so it only includes the process that gives you a messagebox, try to register the server, see the message box, then stop logging of the registry, and read the log bottom-to-top. However, the rel. notes of that update says they fixed some security issues, so I'd try do upgrade the controls instead of the downgrading..

Comment: I've tried to install the unpacked files on two machines (one from group A, one from group B). Group A machine seems to be able to use the ActiveX control from a fresh ocx, but the file still not portable to B's. After trying to install the same set of files to group B machine I've got _Class not registered_ again. But now I'm unable to restore the previous state on this machine: restoring the old versions of the 8 ocx's and running regsvr32 on them does not help.

Comment: I've also checked the procmon log on the excel process of this group B machine. It seems that the only CLSID that the process is unable to recover is {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}. Why is it looking for the null GUID?